# How to shuffle retrieved spree products per taxon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, spree

if i have this chunk of code:

```
@products = @searcher.retrieve_products
```

How to shuffle spree products collection by using it's taxons, on that way so my collection is ordered by following way:

```
product1 | taxon_value_1
product2 | taxon_value_2
product3 | taxon_value_3
product4 | taxon_value_1
product5 | taxon_value_2
product6 | taxon_value_3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try 'Rand()' in your query

```
@products = @searcher.retrieve_products.order('RAND()')
```

This will fetch products and order randomly like shuffling.

Comment: Random isn't sometihng what i want. I want collection to go in order with each next taxon different, then repeat itself while it can, when there isnt any other taxons than previous one, then just append them to collection